# can't get the data Kendo pager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use kendo pager in my project but I can't get the data see the attached  image

```
[result][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmLYn.png

here is my javascript code :
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/Option/Get',
            }
        },
        pageSize: 2,
        schema: {
            data: 'Data',
            model: { id: 'ID' }    
        }
    });
```

the action method  :

```
public JsonResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,int Id)
                {
                    var donnees=_DService.GetList(Id);
                    var results = donnees.ToDataSourceResult(request);
                    return Json(results);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the missing [`schema.total`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.total) setting. Since you are using `ToDataSourceResult`, then it should be set to `"Total"`.

In addition, the action method expects an `Id` parameter, which the Kendo UI DataSource currently does not provide. If you need this parameter to query the database, then use the [`data` function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read.data) of `transport.read` to send it.

Last but not least, call the [`fetch`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-fetch) method of the Kendo UI DataSource instance, unless there is some other widget that will do that automatically (e.g. a ListView).

Here is an example, compare it with your implementation:

http://dojo.telerik.com/okaTeD

This is the dummy data service:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ifEvu

Comment: stil no luck  i get an empty pager